# Regex to validate number between two ranges

Tags: javascript, java, regex, validation

how to validate numbers between 0 to 99999.99 using regex?

basically it should accept the values like `0.01, 0000.01, .01 and 9999.99`

also it should have only `two values after dot(.)`

I tried something like the below but it did not work for me.

```
/^[0-9]{1,5}.[0-9]{2}$/ 

decimal is optional
```

Could someone help pls.

Comment: Is this `javascript` or `java`, and what does *"it did not work for me"* mean?

Answer (score 2):

The `.` character has special meaning in a regex, so you need to escape it.

Anyway, let me see if I got the rules straight:

- Decimal point is optional
- If decimal point not given:

  - Between 1 and 5 digits
- If decimal point is present:

  - Between 0 and 5 digits before decimal point
  - Between 1 and 2 digits after decimal point

Since the number of digits depends on the presence of the decimal point, you make the regex have two choices, separated by `|`.

Choice 1 (no decimal point): `[0-9]{1,5}`

Choice 2 (decimal point): `[0-9]{0,5}\.[0-9]{1,2}`

Since you want anchors (`^$`), you can either put them in both choices, or surround the choice set with parenthesis. To make it non-capturing, use `(?:xxx)`.

Final regex is one of these:

```
/^[0-9]{1,5}$|^[0-9]{0,5}\.[0-9]{1,2}$/
/^(?:[0-9]{1,5}|[0-9]{0,5}\.[0-9]{1,2})$/
```

You can see the second one in effect on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sJ5wY5/1).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript regex:

```
/^\d{1,5}(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

[Javascript demo](https://jsbin.com/gosemewusu/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

If javascript then below regex would work:

```
^\d{0,5}(((\.){0})|((\.){1}\d{1,2}))$
```

All the above mentioned cases are satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you and `^(?:\d{1,5}(?:\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2})$` is what i was trying to get and this serves my purpose.